# Use Mollweide projection in Leaflet, for a Geoserver WMS layer

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, proj, epsg, proj4js

I did a world map in Geoserver, showing in Leaflet in the default projection, which is EPSG:900913 (aka GOOGLE Mercator) but I would like to use the Mollweide projection instead.

I successfully added this grid in Geoserver:

> Name: moll - EPSG:54009 - Extents: -19,844,105   /    -9,922,053    /
> 19,844,105    /   9,922,053   - Tiles : 256x256 - Resolutions: 65,536 - 32,768 - 16,384 - 8,192 - 4,096 - 2,048 - 1,024 - 512 - 256 - 128

I applied the gridset to my layer collection in its settings, and I have a result that I accept, inside Geoserver pointing to the 54009 epsg:

http://mappingforyou.eu/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=pays.monde&bbox=-180.0%2C-90.0%2C180.0%2C83.6236038208008&width=1468&height=670&srs=EPSG%3A54009&styles=&format=application/openlayers

[image]

And though I could load a json data in a Leaflet window, that wms layer won't work.
I have working script links to "proj4js-compressed.js" and "proj4leaflet.js" and an exemple world countries layer "countries-110m.js"

map crs is set to

```
var crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:54009', '+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs', {
    resolutions: [65536, 32768, 16384, 8192, 4096, 2048, 1024, 512, 256, 128] 
});

var map = L.map('map', {
    crs: crs,
    maxZoom: 8
});
```

The Geojson is loading :

```
L.geoJson(countries, {
    style: {
        color: '#000',
        weight: 0.5,
        opacity: 0.2,
        fillColor: '#fff',
        fillOpacity: 0.2
    }          
}).addTo(map);
```

[image]

**the WMS tilelayer is not:**

```
var mapbase = L.tileLayer.wms('http://mappingforyou.eu/geoserver/wms?', { 
       layers: 'pays.monde', 
          maxZoom: 20, 
           crs: crs,
        format: 'image/png', 
                attribution: '↖Menu . Categories↗)' 
}).addTo(map);
```

The browser console is not showing any error. Can you help me please?

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: @IanTurton If I understand question correctly, problem is not in GeoServer part, but in WMS tile layer from http://mappingforyou.eu/geoserver/wms.

Comment: @TomazicM - that's hard to tell with out the log file

Comment: This is a webserver setup problem. Geoserver is running on port 8080, not on the default 80/443. Combine that with browsers nowadays aggressively switching to HTTPS.  BTW your browser console might not be showing any errors, but I betcha that the network tab of the browser's developer tools sure is.

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue might be that Mollweide projection is defined as ESRI:54009 , and not EPSG:54009 (see: https://epsg.io/54009).   If you've still got this issue, perhaps give that a go?

Comment: GeoServer is at present stuck on EPSG, it cannot use any other authority (funding to unlock this welcomed).

Comment: Ahh... thanks for clarifying. I wonder if that's what's causing the problem, because Mollweide (as far as I understand) is not part of the EPSG standard.  It might be something else, but I ran into some issues recently so posted this suggestion as an obvious one to check, since it hasn't been mentioned.